# How to add RMSE, slope, intercept, r^2 to R plot?

Tags: r, plot, statistics

How can I add RMSE, slope, intercept and r^2 to a plot using R?  I have attached a script with sample data, which is a similar format to my real dataset--unfortunately, I am at a stand-still.  Is there an easier way to add these statistics to the graph than to create an object from an equation and insert that into `text()`?  I would ideally like the statistics to be displayed stacked on the graph. How can I accomplish this?

```
## Generate Sample Data
x = c(2,4,6,8,9,4,5,7,8,9,10)
y = c(4,7,6,5,8,9,5,6,7,9,10)

# Create a dataframe to resemble existing data
mydata = data.frame(x,y)

#Plot the data
plot(mydata$x,mydata$y)
abline(fit <- lm(y~x))

# Calculate RMSE
model = sqrt(deviance(fit)/df.residual(fit))

# Add RMSE value to plot
text(3,9,model)
```

Comment: Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549694/ggplot2-adding-regression-line-equation-and-r2-on-graph

Comment: Any ideas on how to add "RMSE = value" in addition to r^2 and an eq for slope and intercept in a neat, formatted fashion?

Comment: You haven't provided any details about what you mean by "formatted fashion". In base graphics, the way you add text to a plot is with `text` (or `mtext`), and you got a link to an excellent answer for ggplot. What problem remains?

Comment: You might also look at the examples in `?plotmath` for some ideas.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is a version using base graphics and `?plotmath` to draw the plot and annotate it

```
## Generate Sample Data
x = c(2,4,6,8,9,4,5,7,8,9,10)
y = c(4,7,6,5,8,9,5,6,7,9,10)

## Create a dataframe to resemble existing data
mydata = data.frame(x,y)

## fit model
fit <- lm(y~x, data = mydata)
```

Next calculate the values you want to appear in the annotation. I prefer `bquote()` for this, where anything marked-up in `.(foo)` will be replaced by the value of the object `foo`. The Answer @mnel points you to in the comments uses `substitute()` to achieve the same thing but via different means. So I create objects in the workspace for each value you might wish to display in the annotation:

```
## Calculate RMSE and other values
rmse <- round(sqrt(mean(resid(fit)^2)), 2)
coefs <- coef(fit)
b0 <- round(coefs[1], 2)
b1 <- round(coefs[2],2)
r2 <- round(summary(fit)$r.squared, 2)
```

Now build up the equation using constructs described in `?plotmath`:

```
eqn <- bquote(italic(y) == .(b0) + .(b1)*italic(x) * "," ~~ 
                  r^2 == .(r2) * "," ~~ RMSE == .(rmse))
```

Once that is done you can draw the plot and annotate it with your expression

```
## Plot the data
plot(y ~ x, data = mydata)
abline(fit)
text(2, 10, eqn, pos = 4)
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: If you want each descriptor on a new line use `\n` instead of `,` in the equation.